# Using small matrices in xypic

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

In `xypic`, I would like to have an arrow between small vertical arrows (bundles) as follows:

```
\xymatrix{
H\ar[r] & \mathsf{hom}\left(\begin{smallmatrix} H\\
\downarrow\\ H \end{smallmatrix},
\begin{smallmatrix} H\\
\downarrow\\ H \end{smallmatrix}\right)\ar[r] & H}
```

However, this won't compile for me on LyX.

Is there any way to stick small vertical column vectors inside the `xymatrix` array?

Comment: please always post full minimal examples not just sniplets, this increases the likelihood that others want to help

Comment: Just add `{....}` around the second cell (not including the `\ar`. BTW `mathtools` has a `bsmallmatrix` env so you don't need the `\left/right()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to brace the `smallmatrix` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\DeclareMathOperator{\shom}{\mathsf{hom}}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
  H\ar[r] & \shom\left({\begin{smallmatrix} H\\
  \downarrow\\ H \end{smallmatrix}},
  {\begin{smallmatrix} H\\
  \downarrow\\ H \end{smallmatrix}}\right)\ar[r] & H
}

\end{document}
```

Better yet, define a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\DeclareMathOperator{\shom}{\mathsf{hom}}

\newcommand{\vertmap}[2]{%
  {\begin{smallmatrix} #1 \\ \downarrow \\ #2 \end{smallmatrix}}%
}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
  H\ar[r] & \shom\left(\vertmap{H}{H},\vertmap{H}{H}\right)\ar[r] & H
}

\end{document}
```

[image]